# zip with iter( ) with variable and with list

Tags: python, zip

```
x = iter([1,2,3,4])
r1 = zip(x, x, x)
r2 = zip(iter([1,2,3,4]),iter([1,2,3,4]),iter([1,2,3,4]))
r3 = zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])

print "r1 = %s"%r1
print "r2 = %s"%r2
print "r3 = %s"%r3

[output]
r1 = [(1, 2, 3)]
r2 = [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
r3 = [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
```

I would like to know why this three output is quite different than i thought.
On my mind, I would guess that r1 is the same result as r2, and r3 is different. But is not.

Comment: OK, you got your answers, but it would have been nicer if you had shown the print results.  Not all your readers can rerun the code on a handy interpreter or in their heads.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks guy, I have edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, there is *only* only iterator, `x`, and it is *referenced* three times in `zip`:

```
>>> x = iter([1,2,3,4])
>>> r1 = zip(x, x, x)
>>> print "r1 = %s"%r1
r1 = [(1, 2, 3)]
```

To make one tuple, zip has to grab three elements from `x`.  The first three available elements are 1, 2, and 3.

In hopes of making a second tuple, zip tries again.  This time, it gets a 4 and then `x` is empty.  It cannot complete a second tuple.  Thus the output is just `[(1, 2, 3)]`.

In the other cases, the arguments to zip are three separate and independent iterables.  Thus, for the first tuple, zip grabs 1, 1, and 1.  For the second, it grabs 2, 2, and 2, and so one:

```
>>> r2 = zip(iter([1,2,3,4]),iter([1,2,3,4]),iter([1,2,3,4]))
>>> r3 = zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> print "r2 = %s"%r2
r2 = [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
>>> print "r3 = %s"%r3
r3 = [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case

```
x = iter([1,2,3,4])
r1 = zip(x, x, x)
```

`zip` is reading first element of every argument because of that `x` is iterated 3 times and returned the values `1`, `2` and `3`. That's why you can see result with value `[1,2,3]`

second time only first argument to `zip` will return value i.e. `4` and second and third argument will not return any value.

r1 and r2 are not using same object, all three objects are newly created and passed as an argument. Whereas for r1 same object is passed.